# Unable to find a matching set of capabilities with selenium 3.4.3, firefox 54.0 and gecko driver 0.17

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
 driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/home/saurabh/Saurabh/LearnPython/Automation/geckodriver');
```

After running the above code I am getting an error as :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any significant error in your code as such.

> It is to be noted that the current Selenium-Python binding is unstable with geckodriver and looks to be Architecture specific. You can find the github [discussion](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884) and [merge](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/pull/685) here. So you may additionally need to pass the absolute path of the firefox binary as `firefox_binary` argument while initializing the **webdriver**

Here is your own code with a simple tweak which opens the Mozilla Firefox browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

if __name__ == '__main__':

    binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe")
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sur you are pointing to `\path\to\FirefoxPortable\App\Firefox64\firefox.exe` and not just `\path\to\FirefoxPortable\FirefoxPortable.exe`

Comment: Thanks a lot - now firefox is starting.