# Unable to find a matching set of capabilities with GeckoDriver

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, pycharm, geckodriver

I'm try to run the selenium python package in Debian 9 Stretch for web-scraping purposes; I installed such versions for the following softwares:

1. Python 2.7.13 (with Pycharm 2018.2 Community Edition)
2. Mozilla Firefox Quantum 61.0.1 (64 bit)
3. Selenium 3.14 (with GeckoDriver v0.21.0)

When I try to call the web driver by running:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/quant/Documenti/Executable/geckodriver")
```

I get the following error message in the python console:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/home/quant/Scrivania/BettingDataDownload/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py",
>   line 167, in **init**
>       keep_alive=True)   File "/home/quant/Scrivania/BettingDataDownload/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 156, in **init**
>       self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)   File "/home/quant/Scrivania/BettingDataDownload/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 251, in start_session
>       response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)   File "/home/quant/Scrivania/BettingDataDownload/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 320, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/home/quant/Scrivania/BettingDataDownload/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable
>   to find a matching set of capabilities

What's wrong?

The path of the executable is correct and the file is executable; moreover, by adding the *firefox_binary* option to the *webdriver.Firefox* function
 as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary="/snap/bin/firefox", executable_path="/home/quant/Documenti/Executable/geckodriver")
```

one gets the same error shown above.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks all.

Comment: Maybe Firefox isn't installed in the default path. Try to pass the Firefox path in the keyworded argument **firefox_binary** in Firefox initialization. You may find useful the documentation: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver

Comment: Thanks for the comment @FedericoRubbi and the link! anyway, by adding the firefox binary option to the webdriver.Firefox function as follows: driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary="/snap/bin/firefox",executable_path="/home/quant/Documenti/Executable/geckodriver") I get the same error!! :( I got the path by running which firefox in the terminal.. any advice??

Comment: The path should be: "/snap/bin/firefox.exe"

Comment: No way! always the same error.. anyway, I think that the .exe format should be used on windows OS only, right?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I thought you were in Windows. Have you tried to add the entire filename of the Firefox file?

Comment: What do you mean @FedericoRubbi? how can I do that?

Comment: Checkout this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601126/unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabilities-with-selenium-3-4-3-firefox-54-0

Comment: Hi @Newcontributor and thanks for the comment! Anyway, no way.. it gives the same error :(